# Does 外行的想法 mean "rookie mistake"?

Tags: word-choice, translation

I found this sentence and its translation on [tatoeba.org](http://tatoeba.org/eng/sentences/show/344579). Is there a better way to translate it into English?

> 這是外行的想法。
>
> That's a layman's idea.

I looked up 外行, and it does mean amateur or layman, but I've never heard anybody use the phrase "layman's idea" in English. Perhaps a better translation would be as simple as, "That's a dumb idea." Or does the Chinese phrase emphasize that it's a bad idea because the person is inexperienced? If so, perhaps it would be best to translate as, "That's a rookie mistake."

Comment: A rookie's opinion sounds better. A suggestion by a rookie/amateur doesn't necessarily culminate in a mistake/blunder.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

English is not my mother tongue, but I would translate 外行的想法 as "unprofessional opinion" or "amateurish opinion".
[外行](http://www.nciku.com/search/all/%E5%A4%96%E8%A1%8C) is the opposite of [内行](http://www.nciku.com/search/all/%E5%86%85%E8%A1%8C), which means *expert, adept, experienced, an expert, a professional*, so the emphasis is as you mentioned on the fact that the person is not experienced.

Comment: It surely sounds like your mother tongue.

Comment: Agreed. The original sentence doesn't sound belittling (although blunt) unless it's intentionally used against a real professional.

Answer (score 4):

外行literally means "outsider." But it can easily be interpreted as "layman" or "non-professional."

外行的想法, would be "outsider or non-professional way of thinking." It's something of a pejorative, because the Chinese culture places a greater emphasis on "expert" or "professional" opinions, as opposed to "whatever works."